# Transfer MySQL Database to SQL Express 2017 with MSSM

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I just begin programming applications, and I need to install a demo of my software. But I read on internet that if I install a software using MySQL, I have obligation to give my source code except if I pay annual licence.(contacted Oracle support 3 months ago, but never got answer).
That's why I decided to transfer database on SQL Server, but now I meet that problem to install it on client's server, any advise about it also would be welcome. Thanks

I have a database in MySQL, and I would like to copy it on Microsoft Server 2017 through MS Server Migration.
On my local computer it works perfectly, but when I try to do it on the server, I have the following warning : SQL Server is not running. You must start SQL Server Agent to use Server-side data migration engine.
When I check services, I see in fact that no agent is running.

Looking on internet, I read that on SQL Express there is no Agent service, and I need to buy SQL Server Entreprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use data migration Free BI tools like `pentaho PDI`

By using this you can easily migrate data from `MSSQL` to `MYsql`

Comment: and from MySQL to MSSQL the same?

Comment: @Siegfried.V yes same you can use that as well

Comment: Well it seems PDI is no more free https://www.hitachivantara.com/go/pentaho.html?source=pentaho-redirect
I am looking for other alternatives on google, if I understand good, what I am looking for is "Data Integration Software"

Comment: PDI has community and enterprise both edition you have find community edition

Comment: @Siegfried.V check that link

Comment: I am on it, keep in touch as soon as I managed to use it, thanks

Comment: @Siegfried.V i used it so i referred it to you i know it will help you a lot, please keep upvote and accept answer as SO appreciation if my guide help you though i already know it definitely help you

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer, I upvoted you, but waiting to check it before to mark it as the good answer, for now I am on their website to try to understand how to install it, thanks

Comment: if you faced any problem on installation share your problem i am here :)